# Application Error on Heroku for Middleman site

Tags: ruby, heroku, static, middleman

I've been following the [Thoughtbot Middleman guide](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/middleman-bourbon-walkthrough). It used to work fine when I pushed to Heroku but it stopped working these past two weeks.

Heroku logs:

```html
2015-04-14T00:28:52.265232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 33769`
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785358+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': undefined method `server' for Middleman:Module (NoMethodError)
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785381+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785384+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785389+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785390+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785385+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785387+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785405+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785392+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785403+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785399+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785400+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785402+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785394+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-04-14T00:28:54.785397+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-04-14T00:28:55.506629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-14T00:28:55.505287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-14T00:28:55.494009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-14T00:28:59.625355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 30791`
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364349+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364325+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>': undefined method `server' for Middleman:Module (NoMethodError)
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364362+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364358+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364356+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364347+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364352+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364351+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364372+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364376+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364410+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364413+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364369+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364412+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364417+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2015-04-14T00:29:02.364365+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2015-04-14T00:29:03.495350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-04-14T00:29:03.512947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-14T00:29:04.147197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-caverns-1614.herokuapp.com request_id=d52f8ceb-4076-4371-b2b4-daf621689b2b fwd="198.2.47.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-14T00:29:04.920600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=afternoon-caverns-1614.herokuapp.com request_id=edc85d48-13ef-4b60-b758-351e8d465a75 fwd="198.2.47.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.31.3 update available.
```

Last two lines show an H10 error which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Is you puma.rb in the right place?

Comment: I didn't need it before; but I just added it to my Gemfile, restart and bundled -still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The problem was Middleman.server in config.ru. Removing it fixes the problem. Having Rack is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Rack server support of Middleman is currently broken after version 3.3.9.

The workaround right now is to use version 3.3.8 or versions before it.

You might want to specify the version in your `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem 'middleman', '3.3.8'
```

p.s. I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1501) on Github for this.